# how to detect input language for creating slug, if not English then slug input remain empty using javascript

Tags: javascript, slug

i am trying to take title input and create slug using it. But if the title is not written in English like "আমার প্রথম পোস্ট" then the slug input will remain empty. The code is given below. hope someone can help. Not good at javascript .

```js
document.getElementById("title").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(this.value)) {
    $(document).on('blur', '#title', function(){
        var TitleInput = $('#title').val().toLowerCase().trim();
        TitleInput = TitleInput.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/g, '-');
        var SlugInput = $('#slug').val(TitleInput);
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById("show_lang_in_here").innerHTML = "Different language";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>Title :</p>
            <input id="title" type="text"> <br>
            <br>
            <p>Slug :</p>
            <input id="slug" type="text">
        </form>

        <div id="show_lang_in_here"></div>

    </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to support special characters from other languages or not?

Comment: Got the answer. See the accepted answer. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to do what I believe you're after, these are the main changes:

- Wait for the document to be loaded with `$(document).ready()`
- I've expanded your regex to allow numbers and spaces as valid English `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/` (There's a lot more you can add to this, it's quite difficult to detect exactly what is valid English)
- You were creating an event listener inside your `if`, instead of actually executing the code (You can listen for multiple events by including them in the `.on('keyup blur')` string)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#title').on('keyup blur', function() {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test($(this).val())) {
      var titleInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/g, '-');
      $('#slug').val(titleInput);
    } else {
      $('#show_lang_in_here').text('Different language');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <p>Title :</p>
    <input id="title" type="text"> <br>
    <br>
    <p>Slug :</p>
    <input id="slug" type="text">
  </form>
  <div id="show_lang_in_here"></div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is replacing by `-`

If you want to remove everything, change it to `TitleInput = TitleInput.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/g, '');`

```js
document.getElementById("title").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(this.value)) {
    $(document).on('blur', '#title', function(){
        var TitleInput = $('#title').val().toLowerCase().trim();
        TitleInput = TitleInput.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/g, '');
        var SlugInput = $('#slug').val(TitleInput);
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById("show_lang_in_here").innerHTML = "Different language";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>Title :</p>
            <input id="title" type="text"> <br>
            <br>
            <p>Slug :</p>
            <input id="slug" type="text">
        </form>

        <div id="show_lang_in_here"></div>

    </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for. But thanks for he effor. :)